# Autocomplete of column names for R data.table doesn't work in Jupyter Notebook / Lab

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, data.table, jupyter-lab

I'm using R in a notebook within JupyterLab but have found the autocomplete of datatable column names doesn't work.

Say I have a datatable called 'dtContracts' with a column called 'TerminationAgreementReference'. If I type dtC and press tab, the autocomplete works for the datatable name.

However, when I type:
`dtContracts[T` and press tab, it just puts side ticks around it like this:
`'dtcontracts[T'` (note I've used normal quotes just now because I couldn't figure out how to escape the ` symbol within a code block.

Has anyone experienced/resolved this issue?

Thanks in advance.